# CEF 120.1.8+ge6b45b0+chromium-120.0.6099.109 Windows Version

Tags: cefsharp

i am a little bit confused about the required Windows version.
According to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3636 only Visual C++ 2019 is required.,
no OS is mentioned.
This supports Win 2012 / Win 8 and above.

According to google chromium runs only with Win 2016/Win 10 and above.

So can i run latest CefSharp on Win 2012 / 8 or not?

Many thanks in advance

Klaus

I am asking for my company, we use a CefSharp component in our application and plan to upgrade to the latest version, and i want to know if we need to force our customers to upgrade thier systems too.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? But keep in mind that Windows 8 is out of support since the beginning of 2023

Answer (score 0):

> So can i run latest CefSharp on Win 2012 / 8 or not?

No.

You can view the official announcement at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4336